# Ethereum Node I want to export transactions from a token

Tags: contract-development, tokens, dapp-development, contract-debugging, etherscan

I have an Ethereum node running and I am wanting to export transaction history for a specific ERC20 token to a local database every 10 minutes.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how they would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to do this.

Since you are running your own node, you can pull the information directly from here and add to your database. To do this, you would perform the following steps:

1. Every 10 minutes, look at the transactions in each block that you have not yet looked at
2. Observe each transaction in each block and look for transactions that are sent to the contract address of the ERC20 token (this is in the `to` field of the transaction parameters).
3. Save the relevant data from each of these transactions in your local database.

The other option is to not use your node at all, but rather use an existing block explorer such as Etherscan. You can perform steps similar to those listed above, except the data would be coming from a 3rd party and not from your node directly.